# Operator notation - numerically stable forward recursions in linear-chain conditional random fields (CRFs)

Tags: machine-learning, notation, conditional-random-field

I would appreciate some clarity on my understanding of some notation for the mathematical specification of forward recursions for inference in linear-chain conditional random fields (CRFs), with a view to its implementation in the log-domain for numerical stability.

**Query.**

My query concerns the indexed operator denoted $\oplus_{i \in S}$ in **equation (4.38)** from the following excerpt from p329-330 of the Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning tutorial [paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf), "An Introduction to Conditional Random Fields" by Sutton, McCallum (2011):

> A second approach to preventing underflow is to perform computations in the logarithmic domain e.g. the forward recursion (4.6) [which I have included for ease of reference]
> $$\begin{equation*}
> \alpha_t (j) = \sum_{i \in S} \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) \alpha_{t-1}(i)
> \tag{4.6}
> \end{equation*}$$
> becomes
> $$\begin{equation*}
> \log \alpha_t (j) = \oplus_{i \in S} (\log \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(i))
> \tag{4.38}
> \end{equation*}$$
> where $\oplus$ is the operator $a \oplus b = \log(e^a + e^b)$. At first this does not seem much of an improvement, since numerical precision is lost when computing $e^a$ and $e^b$. But $\oplus$ can be computed as
> $$\begin{equation*}
> a \oplus b = a + \log(1+e^{b-a}) = b + \log(1 + e^{a-b})
> \tag{4.39}
> \end{equation*}$$
> which can be much more numerically stable if we pick the version of the identity with the smaller exponent.

Where $i$ ranges over the set of discrete states $S = \{1, ..., M\}$, $t$ indexes discrete-time so that equations (4.6) and (4.38) are recursions, and the idea is that we compute $\alpha_t(j)$ and $\log \alpha_t(j)$ for all $j \in S$ also.

I am comfortable with examples of operators in mathematics (e.g. product, summation, expectation etc.), but *lack familiarity* in the sense of never having studied their formal properties as mathematical objects of study. After doing some wiki-ing:

**1. Is the operator $\oplus$ used in this particular context an example of the *direct-sum* operator in the sense of this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)? Or is it idiosyncratically chosen notation on the part of the author?**

**2. Which of the following expansions of the indexing $i \in S$ on this operator in equation (4.38) is correct?:**

$$\begin{equation*}
\log \alpha_t(j) = (\log \Psi_t(j, 1, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(1)) \oplus \space  ... \space \oplus (\log \Psi_t(j, M, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(M))
\tag{A}
\end{equation*}$$

$$\begin{equation*}
\log \alpha_t(j) = (\log \Psi_t(j, 1, x_t) \oplus \log \alpha_{t-1}(1)) + \space  ... \space + (\log \Psi_t(j, M, x_t) \oplus \log \alpha_{t-1}(M))
\tag{B}
\end{equation*}$$

By analogy to the product and summation operators (which may not be appropriately justified), I would expect it to be $(A)$.

However, my confusion stems from wondering if it should be $(B)$, because the author has specifically chosen to present a numerically stable version of $a \oplus b$ in (4.39), known as the "LogSumExp" trick in machine learning, over two terms ($a$ and $b$), rather than over $M$ terms. Adding to my confusion somewhat is the fact that the clique potentials $\Psi_t$ are log-linear functions, with the form $e^{(\cdot)}$. Perhaps this is a case of overthinking leading me astray?

**Further context.**

The forward recursion described in equation (4.6), amongst other purposes, provides a means of efficiently computing the normalisation constant $Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta)$ in conditional random fields (so that the computational complexity is not exponential). In the language of undirected directed graphical models, for *state vectors* $\mathbf{y} = (y_0, y_1, ... , y_T)$ and *observation vectors* $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_T)$, CRFs specify the conditional probability $p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)$ as a product of *clique potentials*, or *factors* $\Psi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t)$, paramterised by $\Theta$:

$$\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta) &= \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta)} \prod^T_{t=1} \Psi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t)\end{align}$$

Where the *clique potentials* are also a weighted linear combination of *feature functions* $f_k(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t)$, with each weight being an element $\theta_k$ of $\Theta = (\theta_1, ..., \theta_K)$:

$$\Psi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t) = \exp \left(\sum^K_{k=1} \theta_k f_k(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t) \right)$$

And the *normalisation constant* $Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta)$ is given by:

$$Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta) = \sum_{y_1} ... \sum_{y_T} \prod^T_{t=1} \Psi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct expansion of $\oplus_{i \in S}(\log \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(i))$ you are looking for is $(A)$.

Taking the logs of the forward recursion in equation (4.6), we have:

$$\begin{align}
\log \alpha_t(j) &= \log \sum_{i \in S} \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) \alpha_{t-1}(i) \\
&= \log \left[\Psi_t(j, 1, x_t) \alpha_{t-1}(1) + ... +  \Psi_t(j, M, x_t) \alpha_{t-1}(M)\right] \\
&= \log \left[e^{\log \Psi_t(j, 1, x_t)} e^{\log \alpha_{t-1}(1)} + ... e^{\log \Psi_t(j, M, x_t)}e^{\log \alpha_{t-1}(M)} \right] \\
&= \log \left[e^{\log \Psi_t(j, 1, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(1)} + ... e^{\log \Psi_t(j, M, x_t) + \log\alpha_{t-1}(M)} \right] \\
&= \oplus_{i \in S}(\log \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(i))
\end{align}$$

Now, using the definition of the operator $\oplus_{i \in S} \space u_i = \log[e^{u_1} +  ... + e^{u_M}]$ where $u_i = \log \Psi_t(j, i, x_t) + \log \alpha_{t-1}(i)$ to compute $\log \alpha_t(j)$ will run into numerical precision errors. Furthermore, notice that $\oplus_{i \in S} u_i$ is of the form $\log \sum_i \exp(u_i)$.

To compute a numerically stable version of this, we use the Log-Sum-Exp trick and instead compute:

$$\begin{align}
\log \alpha_t(j) &= \oplus_{i \in S} \space u_i \\
&= \max \{u_1, ..., u_M \} + \log \left(\sum^M_{i=1} \exp(u_i - \max \{u_1, ..., u_M \}) \right) 
\end{align}$$

Which is the same as $a \oplus b$ generalised to $M$ terms rather than two terms.